# Do not show string if value is equal or greater than another

Tags: string, magento, yaml, price

It is necessary to hide the `oldprice` string if the value of the string is equal to or greater than the `price` string.

What is the correct syntax for a string `oldprice`?

```
 // Save product data into result array
     $result['products'][] = array(
     'id' => $_product->getId(),
     'in_stock' => (bool)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getIsInStock(),
     'url' => str_replace('/index.php', null, $result['shop_data']['url']) . $_product->getUrlKey() . $helper->getProductUrlSuffix(),
     'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
     'oldprice' => $_product->getPrice(),
     'currencyId' => $currencyCode,
     'categoryId' => $_category->getId(),
     'picture' => $picUrl,
     'name' => $_product->getName(),
     'vendor' => trim($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')),
     'model' => $_product->getSku(),
     'description' => trim(strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription())),
     'local_delivery_cost' => $priceship[0],    
     'market_category' => trim($_product->getAttributeText('market_category')),
     'country_of_origin' => trim($_product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture')),
     'local_delivery_cost' => 500,
     'sales_notes' => '100% предоплата',
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 'oldprice' => ($_product->getPrice() >= $_product->getFinalPrice() ? 0 : $_product->getPrice())
```

or just do the calculation beforehand

```
$oldPrice = null;
if ($_product->getPrice() >= $_product->getFinalPrice()) {
    $oldPrice = $_product->getPrice();
}

...

'oldprice' => $oldPrice
```

However, this wouldn't stop a value being saved into your array (in this case 0), so you'd still need some logic where you're echoing it out.

Comment: I just edit the last code and now look like this:
  $oldPrice = $_product->getPrice();
  if ($_product->getFinalPrice() >= $_product->getPrice()) {
      $oldPrice = null;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the product data into the array write a if condition

```
<?php

   $oldprice = null;
   $finalprice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
   $price = $_product->getPrice();
   if($price>=$finalprice)
   {
     $oldprice =  $_product->getPrice();
   }

?>
```

And the intialize the array

```
$result['products'][] = array(
     'id' => $_product->getId(),
     'in_stock' => (bool)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getIsInStock(),
     'url' => str_replace('/index.php', null, $result['shop_data']['url']) . $_product->getUrlKey() . $helper->getProductUrlSuffix(),
     'price' => $finalprice,
     'oldprice' => $price,
     'currencyId' => $currencyCode,
     'categoryId' => $_category->getId(),
     'picture' => $picUrl,
     'name' => $_product->getName(),
     'vendor' => trim($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')),
     'model' => $_product->getSku(),
     'description' => trim(strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription())),
     'local_delivery_cost' => $priceship[0],    
     'market_category' => trim($_product->getAttributeText('market_category')),
     'country_of_origin' => trim($_product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture')),
     'local_delivery_cost' => 500,
     'sales_notes' => '100% предоплата',
 );
```